# Wrong / Undesired Bone Rotation problem with IK rigging

Tags: rigging

Anyone know how to fix it?

I was rigging the legs of a robot. When I setup the IK, and move the control bone to test the result, I found that the leg on left hand side cannot show proper as the right hand side does. I was using the same setting by symmetrize function of the bone.

Here is the blender file. I hope someone can help. Thanks.[image]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1epvhikoV1_exKOxB_Y1INY6L6JZJzmyr/view?usp=sharing

Comment: please try that: Re-symmetrize the left bones, roll 180° the top 2 right bones

Comment: I found that roll 180 degree for the first bone will be fine. It is weird that the symmetry function having problem for that leg, but not for all symmetrized legs.

Comment: Yes as I said I'm a bit lost with how the symmetrize works but I've noticed that you sometimes need to correct the bones orientation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-symmetrize the left bones, roll 180° the top 2 right bones (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>). You sometimes need to correct the bones orientation once symmetrized:

[image]

Comment: Somehow it works, but the result is not as good as the others three legs. it shows some odd flipping while moving forward.

Comment: mm yes you're right, I'm going to dig further

Comment: If so, you can delete your post @moonboots